# How to continue running a process after completing threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I got stuck when I was trying to print the summary of all threads (namely, grand totals of a group of threads).

The C code below runs 10 threads, simulating agents that sell tickets. After running & completing the threads (i.e. after all the tickets are sold), I want to print the list of agents and corresponding number of tickets sold by that agent. However, the main process terminates as soon as it hits the line `pthread_exit(NULL)` (marked with a preceding comment) and the code does not return to `main`, where it is supposed to print the grand totals (this block is marked with a comment as well).

Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

struct ThreadArgs {
    int thNum;
    int *numTickets;
    int *soldTickets;
    sem_t *lock;
};

void *SellTickets(void *th) {
    struct ThreadArgs *thArgs;
    int sleepTime;

    thArgs = th;

    while (1) {
        sleepTime = rand();

        if (sleepTime % 2) {
            usleep(sleepTime % 1000000);
        }

        sem_wait(thArgs->lock);

        if (*thArgs->numTickets == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("There are %3d ticket(s). Agent %d sold a ticket.\n", *thArgs->numTickets, thArgs->thNum);
        (*thArgs->numTickets)--;
        sem_post(thArgs->lock);
        (*thArgs->soldTickets)++;
    }

    sem_post(thArgs->lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void runThreads(int numAgents, int numTickets, int soldTickets[]) {
    struct ThreadArgs thArgs[numAgents];
    int agent;
    pthread_t th[numAgents];
    sem_t lock;

    sem_init(&lock, 1, 1);

    for (agent = 0; agent < numAgents; agent++) {
        thArgs[agent].thNum = agent;
        thArgs[agent].soldTickets = &soldTickets[agent];
        thArgs[agent].numTickets = &numTickets;
        thArgs[agent].lock = &lock;
        pthread_create(&th[agent], NULL, SellTickets, &thArgs[agent]);
    }
    // when debugging, the process terminates here
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    int agent, numAgents, numTickets, soldTickets[10];

    numAgents = 10;
    numTickets = 150;

    for (agent = 0; agent < numAgents; agent++) {
        soldTickets[agent] = 0;
    }

    runThreads(numAgents, numTickets, soldTickets);

    // the process never executes the following block    
    for (agent = 0; agent < numAgents; agent++) {
        printf("Agent %d sold %d ticket(s).\n", agent, soldTickets[agent]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `pthread_exit()` in the main thread?

Comment: @EOF: I've tried your way; I carried the `pthread_exit()` line to the `main` just before the `return` statement. However, this time the threads did not run at all; it only prints the for loop (with zero tickets for all agents) and spits segmentation fault.

Comment: I didn't tell you any way you *could* try. I was asking *why* you are doing what you are doing. None of your code makes sense to me.

Comment: In `runThreads()` replace the call to `pthread_exit(NULL);` by a loop calling  `phtread_join()` for all pthread-ids as returned by `pthread_create()`.

Comment: @alk: Solved my problem. Why don't you consider replying as an answer, so I can vote it as a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_exit()` exits a thread, even the "main"-thread.

If `main()` ends all other thread go down as well.

As the "main"-thread is expected to do some final logging, it should wait until all threads spawned have ended.

To accomplish this in `runThreads()` replace the call to

```
      pthread_exit(NULL);
```

by a loop calling `pthread_join()` for all PThread-IDs as returned by `pthread_create()`.

Also you want to add error checking to all `pthread*()` calls, as you should do for every function call returning any relevant info, like for example indicating ***failure*** of the call.